# Ethereum Goerli

Tags: ethereum, mining

I've run the Ethereum Goerli Network with the following command:

```
geth --goerli --datadir="/mnt/sdc1/ethereum/goerli/" --port="30304"  --cache 4096 --http --http.addr="0.0.0.0" --http.port="8546" --http.vhosts="*" --http.corsdomain="*" --http.api="admin, debug, web3, eth, txpool, personal, clique, miner, net" --authrpc.jwtsecret=/tmp/jwtsecret --authrpc.vhosts="*" --authrpc.port=8553 --allow-insecure-unlock --mine --miner.threads=4  --miner.etherbase '0x...'
```

with enabled miner and etherbase, but mining is not started.
I've seen the next in logs:

```
INFO [07-07|19:01:18.501] Commit new sealing work                  number=7,186,017 sealhash=3033a3..979541 uncles=2 txs=22   gas=29,479,757 fees=0.04464585701   elapsed=108.735ms
WARN [07-07|19:01:18.501] Block sealing failed                     err="unauthorized signer"
```

What's wrong?
How can I enable mining in Ethereum Goerly Network?
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

As of August 11th, 2022, the Goerli network "merged" to be proof-of-stake network secured by validators who stake testnet ETH tokens rather than by miners.

There is a guide on how to become a Goerli validator here, if interested: https://coinmarketcap.com/alexandria/article/how-to-set-up-an-eth-2-0-validator-on-goerli-testnet